# Different array types, for comparison in the set_difference() function

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm having some issues getting expected results from `set_difference()`. I assumed I was comparing two dynamic arrays, but I'm not sure where the gap is. The only additional insight I have is that when I compare the two arrays using the `gettype()` function, I get the following:

**First array**

- Created using a make_list aggregation, e.g.

```
| summarize inv_list = make_list(Date)
```

- When I run gettype() on the array:

```
"type_inv_list": array
```

**Second array**

- Created through a scalar function

```
let period_check_range = todynamic(range(make_datetime(start_date), datetime_add('day',8,make_datetime(start_date)),1d));
```

- When I run gettype() on the array:

```
"type_range___scalar_90e56a216d8942f28e6797e5abc35dd9": array
```

Any guidance on how to make these arrays work so I can use the `set_difference()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `toscalar()` (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction)) in the first array. When you run `| summarize ...` you get a table as a result, but what you actually want is a single scalar, what's why `toscalar()` is needed.

Here's how to achieve what you want:

```
let StartDate = ago(10d);
let Array1 = toscalar(MyTable | summarize make_set(Timestamp));
let Array2 = todynamic(range(make_datetime(StartDate), datetime_add('day',8,make_datetime(StartDate)),1d));
print set_difference(Array2, Array1)
```

By the way, you probably want to use `make_set` and not `make_list` as you're not interested in duplicate values.

Comment: Brilliant. Worked like a charm. That's exactly where the gap was on my side. Thank you!

Comment: @thomassantosh, glad this helped. Will appreciate if you mark the answer as accepted, by clicking the green "V", thank you!

Comment: Right on. Thanks again for the help.